# HTTP error upon running installation

Tags: php, windows, symfony, installation

I am attempting to install the symfony php framework on windows

i have ran the command

```
c:\>php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

and copied the file to my projects directory

```
copy symfony c:\developmentStack\www\knoxville_programmers
```

and yet upon executing the installation file

```
c:\developmentStack\www\knoxville_programmers> php symfony
```

i receive the following error message

```
Warning: readfile(http://symfony.com/installer): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in Command line code on line 1
```

anyone know a solution to this i have searched sensio labs dry looking for community help and it doesn't seem many others have had the problem

Comment: it seems to be HTTP error, any issues with network connectivity?

Comment: I am at a local coffee shop perhaps i should try on my home network?

Comment: Yes. :) Try again with a good connection.

Comment: @Arjun, He's getting a 404, meaning connectivity is not a problem. How would he even post here without having a connection to the internet?

Comment: I suggest you to use composer - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html - It will allow you to use packages of https://packagist.org/

Comment: @HPierce I guessed it would either be a connectivity issue, because everything he did seems to be in accordance to the documentation.

Comment: i was afraid you would say that @zlen haha i will try that alternative

Comment: Since I discovered composer, I can"t do without!, Some framework whatsoever.

Comment: wow so  @zlen my problem was i was attempting to run all these commands within my node.js command prompt environment which is literally appears exactly the same just configured for use of npm and node which somehow affected this greatly haha

Comment: OK, so problem solved ? ;)